# Get Request Attributes in Restlet 2.0

Tags: java, rest, restlet-2.0

I'm using [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) to make a RESTful platform.  I haven't used it before, but I decided to use 2.0 because it is better to start with the latest and greatest technology, right?

The key thing I am looking for is the ability to have someone to put in a URL like `http://mysite/New%20York/3` and have the service respond with something like `[New York,New York,New York]`, so I need to pass in request attributes.  Using this post for [Restlet 1.1](http://danilogurovich.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/a-simple-restlet-demo-application/) (because I can't seem to find *any* documentation for this on the Restlet site), I wired up my application like so:

```
router.attach("{text}/{count}", RepeaterResource.class);
```

The new way to do this is apparently in the `UniformResource#doInit()` method, so mine looks like (without error checking):

```
@Override
public void doInit()
{
    magicText = "" + getRequestAttributes().get("text");
    repeatAmount = Integer.parseInt("" + getRequestAttributes().get("count"));
}
```

The problem is that the `Map<String, Object>` returned from `getRequestAttributes()` is always completely empty!  This seems rather odd.  Am I wiring the routing up wrong?

Of course, I could just use `getQuery()` and parse it myself, but that is definitely the wrong way to go about doing this and it seems like there should be an easy way to do this (similar to the way previous versions worked).

Comment: *"... because it is better to start with the latest and greatest technology, right?"* - Not necessarily.  You need to figure out if the benefits of using the new technology outweigh the risks and costs for your project.  And don't neglect the long term problems your successors will have if the technology is just a fad that everyone abandons in a couple of years.

Comment: :-P I agree with you, although this irritating little issue seems easily resolvable by someone who knows what they are doing (which means I have no idea).

Comment: I agree with Stephen, but just to bring this down to the concrete: Restlet has been in use in production systems for years, is well maintained, and has a strong community. 2.0 has been in development for a very long time, over a year, and is at this point very stable - the current version is RC4, and the final release will be out soon. So I think it's a safe choice — not as safe as 1.1, which is even more mature, but safe nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem, is seems, is that router attachments must start with the `/` character.  I should attached like so:

```
router.attach("/{text}/{count}", RepeaterResource.class);
```

I can't seem to find this behavior documented and it seems rather odd, but it certainly fixed my issues.

Comment: Do you still use Restlet? I'm having the same issue but I have in my add the "/" but still does not work...

Comment: Sorry, no -- I've moved on to Scala.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 2.0 the same way as with 1.1.

See the tutorial, part 11: http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/tutorial#part11

Restlet is great, BTW.